# Issue in creating unlocked package in SFDX format

Tags: salesforcedx

We have converted existing slaesforce application into SFDX format and while trying to create unlocked package, I am getting below error:

1. Unable to upload a field update action that sets a record owner field to a queue. To continue, set the record owner field to a user, which will be replaced by the user installing the app.
2. Target object does not have a valid lookup or master-detail reference to the parent object
3. Target object does not have a valid lookup or master-detail reference to the parent object
4. Unable to upload a field update action that sets a record owner field to a queue. To continue, set the record owner field to a user, which will be replaced by the user installing the app.

Any hint/help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Deepak Singh